# Executing Interval output on background IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nstimer, multipeer-connectivity

Ok , im not getting answers about this.  :(

[Multipeer Connectivity audio streaming stop work on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856978/multipeer-connectivity-audio-streaming-stop-work-when-app-put-on-background)

What about this?

i'm trying to run  this code on background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

       [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
       bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:3
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(showInformation)
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
           addTimer:aTimer
           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });

}
```

Obviously i ihave this function defined on the same scope

```
- (void) showInformation {
  NSLog(@"showInformation is called.");
}
```

But  when i put the app on background, the interval message, stop work and when i come back  to the foreground continue working ........

This means is not running on the background?.

Is this possible? or am I trying to do something stupidly impossible?

I really appreciate some help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless your code works or not, your background task will be terminated after a while (>10 minutes) by iOS unless the UIBackgroundModes is set in your app (VOIP, Location service, Audio ..).

For more about Background Execution check [Background Execution and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).

Another option in iOS7 is using [Background Fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW10), but you don't have control over time (there is a smart Timer used by the iOS).

For better understanding check Raywenderlich's [Background Modes in iOS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios).

And if you need something working check the below SO posts:

[How do I get a background location update every n minutes in my iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347503/how-do-i-get-a-background-location-update-every-n-minutes-in-my-ios-application?lq=1)

[Running iOS App in background for more than 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031120/running-ios-app-in-background-for-more-than-10-minutes?rq=1)

[Will iOS launch my app into the background if it was force-quit by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/ios-7-background-fetch-by-push-notification-will-ios-launch-my-app-if-it-is-no)

Comment: Ok, i understand , I was reading all this post and not works for me,  this not work 10 minutes, this never run in background, I have enabled VOIP , any more ideas? Thanks

Comment: OK man I just wanted to save your time ;), VOIP works fine for me, but be careful your app should be VOIP or it gets rejected, this solution should work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4808049/1262634

Comment: When you execute the code with VOIP background mode enabled?  you receive output on background mode? .....

Comment: The code in the question print something each 3 seconds, but when you put the app on background stop printing. The question is. Exist some way to keep printing the output on background mode, for some time?